# How can i update my old motherboard and BIOS?

Tags: drivers, bios

I am trying to update my BIOS on my old motherboard: ASUS M2N32 WS Pro, current version is 0304, i went to the official support website yet there is no recent update, i need an update dating from 2011 or 2012, i want to know if my motherboard and my BIOS are still receiving updates?

Comment: Why do you need an upgrade?

Comment: I need it because i was told it might solve my problem with Rome 2.

Comment: Perhaps if you add the actual issue you are having it might help solve the issue even if there are no BIOS updates

Comment: `I need it because i was told it might solve my problem with Rome 2`   By whom? Did they say that it would fix the problem for your specific board or were they just talking generically and saying useless catch-all stuff like “update your drivers” without actually paying attention to your specific case?

Answer (score 1):

[Contact your manufacturer; they will be able to tell you directly the most up-to-date driver for your motherboard.](http://support.asus.com/contactus.aspx)

Many manufacturers of older, legacy devices have archived updates available online which aren't really advertised on their public-facing website. I can't find one for Asus from a quick google-fu, but I daresay there is one out there. They tend to be FTP servers just open up to the public to browse via a web browser - again, contacting them may tell you more.

I will say, steer clear of any 'custom' motherboard drivers - they do exist, and they are often a very risky. A motherboard flash gone wrong is a huge problem, because they are much harder to recover from and sadly, the only people that truly know motherboard architecture are those who developed it.