# Intel PC prototype, ACPI BIOS ERROR

Tags: boot, usb, motherboard, bios, acpi

Update: The problem is not fixed, but I found out that the motherboard I use is to old to be updated, so I figured I would not invest too much time into it, and I installed an esxi instead of windows server 2016.

Received an oldish Intel Prototype PC from my workplace, there is no manuals on it and the information I can gather is few.

Intel Xeon processor system.

Platform: codename Romley-EP

Processor: codenamed Sandy Bridge CO

Chipset: codenamed Patsburg CO -B

System: codenamed Canoe Pass

Motherboard serial number: E99552-303

I have search google and SuperUsers this is some of the threads I found similary to my own problem:

[Frustrating ACPI BIOS ERROR at boot. HP 15-G019WM UEFI laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/1052016/frustrating-acpi-bios-error-at-boot-hp-15-g019wm-uefi-laptop)

[How can i update my old motherboard and BIOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/674159/how-can-i-update-my-old-motherboard-and-bios)

While there is a possiblity that the one of the ram sticks do not work, I rather not have to go through all 64GB one by one. Unless I run out of options. Updating my BIOS have crossed my mind, but the computers motherboard have been discontinued and I am frankly confused if I can still get the drivers.

The process:

I created a bootable USB with Windows Server 2016, the computer detect the USB and I am able to boot into it.
The files load but as the windows logo appears i receive a Blue Screen Of Death with the error message **ACPI BIOS ERROR**.

What I have tried(in order):

- Using the USB media on a laptop computer (It works fine)
- Install Linux, works flawlessly.
- Load default BIOS settings.
- Removing CSMO battery, wait 15 minutes then replug it in.
- Creating a Hirens bootable CD, however same error after windows splash screen.

Question: 
How do I proceed from here?

Comment: You havent asked a question, all you have done is told a story.

Comment: Does the MOBO have removable BIOS flash chip?

Answer (score 0):

Very partial answer:

Under Linux, type `dmesg` after boot and have a look at the ACPI related messages - this may give a hint about what's wrong with the ACPI tables in the BIOS.

Linux has to be very lenient when dealing with ACPI tables, because it happens frequently that those table violate the (pretty complicated) standard, but work fine with the Windows drivers supplied by the BIOS manufacturer.

Linux also includes tools like `iasl` to compile/decompile ACPI tables, so you can debug the problem yourself. This will require a *lot* of reading (start with the [standard](http://www.uefi.org/acpi/specs
)), so plan to sink quite a bit of time into this if you want to fix it.

Linux also has a tool called `flashrom` which supports a wide range (but not all) flashable hardware found on motherboards, so chances are you can re-flash your BIOS with the fixed ACPI tables, even if it's a PC prototype and there's no chance of getting a vendor supplied BIOS flash program.

Comment: I will look into this, thank you a ton for your quick reply :)